Why does CSS Grid allow text to overflow their containers?
I have some text at a narrow width, with word-break: break-word and hyphens: auto. With normal flow display, the text wraps and stays within the boundaries of the container as I would expect. However, with CSS Grid, the text is allowed to escape the container and the word break happens at a different point.
Why does this happen?


#wrapper {
  max-inline-size: 25ch;
  margin-inline: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

#grid,
#flow {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: oldlace;
}

#flow {
  margin-block-start: 2em;
}

.tag {
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: azure;
  inline-size: min-content;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="grid">
    <p class="tag">grid</p>
    <h2>This is a long headline with a verysuperlongtimeword</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tortor nisl, sagittis ac lectus et, blandit varius leo. Sed vel finibus nunc. Nam ipsum mi, mattis quis cursus id, hendrerit tristique dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
      per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis eu placerat quam, vitae pretium tellus. Sed consequat tellus eu diam commodo, quis ultricies libero ultrices. Praesent nec ipsum venenatis, semper magna at, pretium tortor. Aliquam tempus lectus iaculis
      lacus pretium sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse dictum, felis eu pulvinar scelerisque, risus diam rutrum velit, vel lacinia leo risus vel purus. Integer ipsum
      justo, auctor eu volutpat non, pellentesque a est. Maecenas sollicitudin fermentum mauris, egestas viverra augue congue vitae. Nam non nisi urna. Nullam non cursus orci.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="flow">
    <p class="tag">flow</p>
    <h2>This is a long headline with a verysuperlongtimeword</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tortor nisl, sagittis ac lectus et, blandit varius leo. Sed vel finibus nunc. Nam ipsum mi, mattis quis cursus id, hendrerit tristique dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
      per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis eu placerat quam, vitae pretium tellus. Sed consequat tellus eu diam commodo, quis ultricies libero ultrices. Praesent nec ipsum venenatis, semper magna at, pretium tortor. Aliquam tempus lectus iaculis
      lacus pretium sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse dictum, felis eu pulvinar scelerisque, risus diam rutrum velit, vel lacinia leo risus vel purus. Integer ipsum
      justo, auctor eu volutpat non, pellentesque a est. Maecenas sollicitudin fermentum mauris, egestas viverra augue congue vitae. Nam non nisi urna. Nullam non cursus orci.</p>
  </div>

</div>



https://codepen.io/bronzehedwick/pen/zYVbNWK

Please turn your code into a runnable snippet, right here, not on an external site. Also, what's the point in using grid without defining an actual grid? You have neither declared grid-template-rows nor grid-template-columns. What grid do you expect to get?

Which browser and O/S ? I don't see any such text overflow.

Sure, but what's the point in that? Those tracks will all be auto.

@connexo It's not required to use grid-templates to define explicit tracks. Grid can also generate implicit tracks automatically when needed. Though I agree i don't see why the use of Grid expect using the gap.

@connexo I agree, don't see any point of using grid here. Appologize that I just lost my internet connection and didn't notice you replied before I re-commented.

Regardless of whether or not you would use a grid to create this layout, this is a perfectly valid question; indeed it is a great question. Why does text wrapping behaviour change when an element is inside a grid? Upvoted.

@Alohci in all the browsers unless there is one of them not following the spec (Safari maybe?). I see the same behavior on Chrome and Firefox.

@SyndRain the point is to understand a behavior. The OP provided a minimal code that doesn't necessarily represent a useful use case or a real code.

CSS grid applies a default min-width configuration to its grid items preventing them from shrinking past a minimum size which is basically equal to "min-content".
In your case, the min-content is defined by the longest word verysuperlongtimeword. If you inspect the grid, you can easily notice this.

And since it's a grid, that item will define the width of the column where all the items will get placed so even the text below it will have that same width and will overflow as well.
To fix this, you have to disable the min-width constraint by using min-width: 0


#wrapper {
  max-inline-size: 25ch;
  margin-inline: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

#grid,
#flow {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: oldlace;
}

#flow {
  margin-block-start: 2em;
}

.tag {
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: azure;
  inline-size: min-content;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
}

#grid > * {
  min-width: 0;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="grid">
    <p class="tag">grid</p>
    <h2>This is a long headline with a verysuperlongtimeword</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tortor nisl, sagittis ac lectus et, blandit varius leo. Sed vel finibus nunc. Nam ipsum mi, mattis quis cursus id, hendrerit tristique dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
      per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis eu placerat quam, vitae pretium tellus. Sed consequat tellus eu diam commodo, quis ultricies libero ultrices. Praesent nec ipsum venenatis, semper magna at, pretium tortor. Aliquam tempus lectus iaculis
      lacus pretium sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse dictum, felis eu pulvinar scelerisque, risus diam rutrum velit, vel lacinia leo risus vel purus. Integer ipsum
      justo, auctor eu volutpat non, pellentesque a est. Maecenas sollicitudin fermentum mauris, egestas viverra augue congue vitae. Nam non nisi urna. Nullam non cursus orci.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="flow">
    <p class="tag">flow</p>
    <h2>This is a long headline with a verysuperlongtimeword</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tortor nisl, sagittis ac lectus et, blandit varius leo. Sed vel finibus nunc. Nam ipsum mi, mattis quis cursus id, hendrerit tristique dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
      per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis eu placerat quam, vitae pretium tellus. Sed consequat tellus eu diam commodo, quis ultricies libero ultrices. Praesent nec ipsum venenatis, semper magna at, pretium tortor. Aliquam tempus lectus iaculis
      lacus pretium sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse dictum, felis eu pulvinar scelerisque, risus diam rutrum velit, vel lacinia leo risus vel purus. Integer ipsum
      justo, auctor eu volutpat non, pellentesque a est. Maecenas sollicitudin fermentum mauris, egestas viverra augue congue vitae. Nam non nisi urna. Nullam non cursus orci.</p>
  </div>

</div>



You may also think that word-break: break-word and hyphens: auto should avoid this but no. The minimum size is calculated before applying those properties, then the width of the column is defined and only later we consider those properties. They will have no effect since there is enough space for the longest word which is logical since that same word is the one defining that space.

I can’t explain why this happens, although the fact that this behaviour is consistent across Safari/Chrome (whose codebases have a common origin) and Firefox (whose codebase is completely separate) indicates that the behaviour probably derives from the standards.
However, I have discovered an easy workaround. Set overflow: hidden on #grid h2, and it behaves as per the flow layout.


#wrapper {
  max-inline-size: 25ch;
  margin-inline: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

#grid, #flow {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: oldlace;
}

#flow {
  margin-block-start: 2em;
}

.tag {
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: azure;
  inline-size: min-content;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
}

#grid h2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="grid">
    <p class="tag">grid</p>
    <h2>This is a long headline with a verysuperlongtimeword</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tortor nisl, sagittis ac lectus et, blandit varius leo. Sed vel finibus nunc. Nam ipsum mi, mattis quis cursus id, hendrerit tristique dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
      per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis eu placerat quam, vitae pretium tellus. Sed consequat tellus eu diam commodo, quis ultricies libero ultrices. Praesent nec ipsum venenatis, semper magna at, pretium tortor. Aliquam tempus lectus iaculis
      lacus pretium sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse dictum, felis eu pulvinar scelerisque, risus diam rutrum velit, vel lacinia leo risus vel purus. Integer ipsum
      justo, auctor eu volutpat non, pellentesque a est. Maecenas sollicitudin fermentum mauris, egestas viverra augue congue vitae. Nam non nisi urna. Nullam non cursus orci.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="flow">
    <p class="tag">flow</p>
    <h2>This is a long headline with a verysuperlongtimeword</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tortor nisl, sagittis ac lectus et, blandit varius leo. Sed vel finibus nunc. Nam ipsum mi, mattis quis cursus id, hendrerit tristique dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent
      per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis eu placerat quam, vitae pretium tellus. Sed consequat tellus eu diam commodo, quis ultricies libero ultrices. Praesent nec ipsum venenatis, semper magna at, pretium tortor. Aliquam tempus lectus iaculis
      lacus pretium sollicitudin. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse dictum, felis eu pulvinar scelerisque, risus diam rutrum velit, vel lacinia leo risus vel purus. Integer ipsum
      justo, auctor eu volutpat non, pellentesque a est. Maecenas sollicitudin fermentum mauris, egestas viverra augue congue vitae. Nam non nisi urna. Nullam non cursus orci.</p>
  </div>

</div>



